# Failed to get each file coverage at react app With WebdriverIO

Tags: reactjs, selenium, code-coverage, webdriver-io, devtools

I want to get each code file coverage of react app in http://localhost:3000 with WebdriverIO.

```
react-scripts start
```

But, I only get bundle coverage below.
What can I do?

```
├── coverage
│   ├── cobertura-coverage.xml
│   ├── files
│   │   └── localhost
│   │       └── static
│   │           └── js
│   │               ├── bundle.js
│   │               ├── main.chunk.js
│   │               └── vendors~main.chunk.js
```

```
wdio.conf.js

services: [
    'chromedriver',
    [
        'devtools', {
            coverageReporter: {
                enable: true,
                type: 'cobertura',
                logDir: './coverage'
            }
        }
    ]
]
```

react-scripts: 4.0.1
@wdio/cli: 7.12.6

Comment: I have similar problems with an electron app
my code in wdio.conf.js is similar, but i get this error (after all tests where run sucessful)
`ERROR @wdio/utils:shim: Error: Couldn't capture coverage data for page`